# Rational Function Is Eventually Greater Than 0

Tags: limits, rational-functions

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$.

Let $a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $b_1, ..., b_m \in \mathbb{R}$.

Assume $\displaystyle\frac{a_n}{b_m} > 0.$

Let $f(x) = \displaystyle\frac{a_n x^n + a_{n - 1} x^{n - 1} + ... + a_1 x + a_0}{b_m x^m + b_{m - 1} x^{m - 1} + ... + b_1 x + b_0}$

So far, I have managed to prove that as $x \rightarrow \infty, f(x) \rightarrow \displaystyle\frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m}$.

In other words,

$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R} \textrm{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x > x_0 \Rightarrow \bigg| f(x) - \displaystyle\frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m} \bigg| < \varepsilon$.

When defining limits as $x \rightarrow \infty$, only $x$ values greater than zero need to be considered.

$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists x_0 > 0 \textrm{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x > x_0 \Rightarrow \bigg| f(x) - \displaystyle\frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m} \bigg| < \varepsilon$

Since $\frac{a_n}{b_m} > 0$ and in the case that $x > x_0 > 0$,

$\frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m} > 0$

Therefore, $f(x)$ is eventually always positive.

I would like to prove formally that $\exists M \in \mathbb{R} \textrm{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x > M \Rightarrow f(x) > 0.$

What I have tried so far:

I take $\varepsilon = \displaystyle\frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m}$ so I can get a result of $f(x) > 0$.

However, $x_0$ depends on $\varepsilon$ and $M$ depends on $x_0$. This leads to $M$ depending on $x$ which is illegal since $x$ must be declared after $M$.

I need help doing this in the right order.

Comment: Are you assuming $n \ge m$?

Comment: "So far, I have managed to prove that as $x \rightarrow \infty, f(x) \rightarrow \displaystyle\frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m}$"   ... But If $n > m$ then $\frac {a_n}{b_n}x^{n-m} \to \infty$ is easy to prove  And if $n=m$ then $\frac {a_n}{b_n}x^{n-m} = \frac {a_n}{b_n}$. And if $n < m$ then $\frac {a_n}{b_n}x^{n-m} \to 0$ is easy to prove.

Comment: And the statement "$x \rightarrow \infty, f(x) \rightarrow \displaystyle\frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m}$" doesn't actually make any sense as $x$ is not fixed.  so you can't have *limit* expressed in terms of the *variable* that is itself not bounded.  You can have $\lim f(x) = \lim x \frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m}$ but *not* $\lim f(x) =  x \frac{a_n}{b_m} x^{n - m}$

Comment: f(x) becomes closer to another function in terms of x, so doesn't that follow from the same definition as a limit?

Comment: "f(x) becomes closer to another function in terms of x, so doesn't that follow from the same definition as a limit?"  No... it doesn't.  The limit refers to values.  Not functions.

Comment: Your statement seems to say, for example, that $$\left\lvert\frac{x^4+x^3}{x^2}-x^2\right\rvert\to0$$ as $x\to\infty$

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to say. The difference between the two functions approaches 0.

Comment: So how do I use it to prove that f(x) is eventually greater than 0. Or is there another way?